# not show image from public folder laravel

Tags: laravel, image, routes

I created api for getting image from server and show user but when enter url in server shows (Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.)

notice: request work in localhost

Comment: please put your code here

Comment: (a) are you sure the image exists? (b) have you ran `php artisan storage:link` on the server? (c) Are you sure the URLs generated are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
<img alt="image name" src="{{ url('image/imagename.jpeg') }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to use `public_path()` function:

```
<img src="{{ public_path($IMAGE_PATH) }}">
```